# Rotating an object between -45 and 45 degrees not behaving as expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, degrees

I'm trying to have an object oscillate between -45 and 45 degrees, and the following is the code I am using. Note that `direction` is initialized to 1, `zRotation` to 360, and `speed` to 100. This works perfectly fine. However, when I change `speed` to 1000, the object does a complete 360 rotation before continuing to oscillate correctly. I'm confused why that happens.

This is my code(inside the `Update` method):

```
zRotation += speed * Time.deltaTime * direction;
var newRotation = 
   Quaternion.Euler(
      new Vector3(
         0, 
         0, 
         zRotation));

if (zRotation < 315)
   direction = 1;
if (zRotation > 405)
   direction = -1;

transform.rotation = newRotation;
```

I am using the values 315(-45 degrees) and 405(45 degrees) because it is easier to determine if my object has reached -45 and 45 degrees this way.

I'm aware that this behavior can easily and more cleanly be achieved using Lerp, but this is for an assignment and we haven't covered Lerp yet, so I don't want to use material that hasn't been taught yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you do not limit the `zRotation` values between your desired values. In the current state of your code you only rely on your computer being fast and having little `Time.deltaTime` values (the time elapsed since the last frame).
If you have any kind of hiccup (which happens often in the first couple of frames after starting up), the `Time.deltaTime` value is going to be relatively large, resulting in a `zRotation` that is so large that it takes longer to return into the [-45...45] range. You can check this by adding a line of

`Debug.Log($"Time: {Time.deltaTime} - Rotation: {zRotation}");`

to your update method.

This way the following scenario can occur (each line is the log of a frame):

0. Time: 0 - Rotation: 360
1. Time: 0,02 - Rotation: 380
2. Time: 0,02 - Rotation: 420
3. Time: 0,333 - Rotation: 733,33

In the last step there was a `deltaTime` value that was so big that caused the `zRotation` to get loose and go really far from your desired range.
If you limit the rotation values with

`zRotation = Mathf.Min(Mathf.Max(zRotation, 315), 405);`

You would not go out of the desired range. (Of course you have to update your if statements from `<` to `<=` or you could leave some kind of threshold in the `Min(Max())` part.

I would also advise you use the modulo operator (`%`) and initialize the value of `zRotation` to `0` so that you don't have to constantly keep track of the 360-minAngle, 360+minAngle values, you could just use the angles in a much easier way and the modulo operator helps you stay in the [-360...360] range.

I updated your code:

```
public class Rotator : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float direction = 1;
    private float zRotation = 0;   // zRotation initialized to 0 instead of 360
    public float speed = 1000;

    void Update()
    {
        zRotation += (speed * Time.deltaTime * direction) % 360;  // Use of the modulo operator
        zRotation = Mathf.Min(Mathf.Max(zRotation, -45), 45);   // Limiting the angles so the object does not 'spin out'

        //If you want to see what's going on in the log
        Debug.Log($"Time: {Time.deltaTime} - Rotation: {zRotation}");

        var newRotation =
           Quaternion.Euler(
              new Vector3(
                 0,
                 0,
                 zRotation));

        if (zRotation <= -45)  // LTE because of the limitation to -45
            direction = 1;
        if (zRotation >= 45)   /// GTE because of the limitation to 45
            direction = -1;


        transform.rotation = newRotation;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your point about taking the Min and Max to limit my ranges makes perfect sense, and that seemed to completely fix my issue. So thanks! But it got me thinking about the modulo addition you made. On a normal calculator, -1 % 360 gives an answer of 359 which (if Unity behaved this way) would completely break the code since it would be adding 359 to zRotation then limiting it at 45 repeatedly. The direction would continue to be negative and zRotation will be stuck at 45 indefinetely. It seems however that Unity does not treat modulo this way. Instead, -1 % 360 seems to return -1.

Comment: I tried removing the modulo and the code worked perfectly fine using a speed of 1000. I assume the modulo is there to handle cas es where speed is much much higher than 1000, is this correct? i.e. the increment goes beyond 360

Comment: Yes, if you use -1 % 360 in C# (also in Unity), the result is going to be -1. When you “mod” something, you divide one number by another and take the signed remainder. So I should have said remainder operator to be more precise. 

Yes, the modulo will prevent the zRotation from going over 360 with really big speeds.